# Does Angular 11 support ngAfterViewInit() or AfterViewInit?

Tags: angular

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
   `this.initializeDateSettings(.....);`
}
```

Is this supported by angular 11?

Comment: Yes, it is supported. Have you even tried it?

Comment: Why would you think it wasn't? It's been part of angular@core since v2

Comment: yes, I did try it, the problem is that, the code we  are working on was fine for angular 6 but once we migrated to angular 11  there was an issue. Thank you so much for the information :) .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, ngAfterViewInit() will support in Angular 11 lifecycle.
A lifecycle hook is called after Angular has fully initialized a component's view. Define a ngAfterViewInit() method to handle any additional initialization tasks.

https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit

Answer (score 0):

I just want to explain this life cycle hook. I hope this will help you to understand more about this.

This is the import when we import we use "AfterViewInit";

```
import { AfterViewInit } from @angular/core;
```

And also when we implement with class name we use `AfterViewInit`:

```
export class Home implements AfterViewInit {
}
```

When we use as a method than we should use `ngAfterViewInit()`.

This is the requirements of the angular.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

}
```